# Text box shows popup automatically

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, popup

I have a form in VB.NET 2010 and a popup control within the form.
When I press `Enter key`, in any textbox in my form the pop will automatically be displayed but I don't want to display the pop up in textbox on press of the `enter key`.

Comment: Can you show us some code? It's hard to guess what's happening without.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason might be because of Validation and AutoPostBack are true.
Change

```
    CausesValidation="False" 
    AutoPostBack="False"
```